# Depurar un proyecto de python en Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

Tengo un proyecto de *python* con la siguiente estructura

```
pyFEM
|-.vscode
| |-.env
| |-settings.json
|-dist
| |-pyFEM-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
| |-pyFEM-1.0.0.tar.gz
|-pyFEM
| |-__init__.py
| |-classtools.py
| |-core.py
| |-primitives.py
| test
| |-__init__.py
| |-space_frame.py
| |-trusses.py
|-LICENSE
|-mydata.json
|-README.md
|-setup.py
```

En el archivo `settings.json` tengo

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/rvcristiand/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${env:PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}/src",
    },
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/.env"
}
```

Y en el archivo .env tengo

```
PYTHONPATH=./pyFEM
```

Con dicha configuración puedo ejecutar el archivo `core.py` el cual importa los siguientes módulos

```
from pyFEM.primitives import *

import numpy as np
import json
```

Sin embargo, cuando trato de depurar dicho archivo, obtengo el siguiente error

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pyFEM'
  File "/home/rvcristiand/Documents/projects/pyFEM/pyFEM/core.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyFEM.primitives import *
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a configurar apropiadamente el proyecto para que me permita depurarlo.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Con depurar te refieres a poder ejecutarlo directamente, como módulo principal?

Comment: Con depurar me refiero a poder hacerle debug (F5 en VSCode)